# Почему не происходит refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, html

По какой-то причине не происходит Resfresh страницы, но код правильно вставляется, куда надо. Просто самого факта рефреша не происходит.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title></title>
 <script src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <button>Рефреш</button>
</body>
<script>
 $('button').on('click', function() {
  $.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         url: "test.php",
         data: {lol: 1}, 
         success: function(jqXHR) {
           document.body.innerHTML = jqXHR;
         }
     });
 })

 
</script>
</html>
```

```
<?php
    echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="0;URL=http://www.site.com/">';
?>
```

Comment: `document.head.innerHTML = ...`

Comment: @Igor, уже попробовал, это тоже не работает

Comment: Какой сложный способ сделать рефреш. А зачем?

Comment: попробуйте ```window.location.reload();```